# How would you solve this $9$ system of equations with multi variables?

Tags: matrices

> **Question:** Solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\theta,\lambda,\upsilon,\phi,\omega$ in the following:$$\begin{cases}\alpha r+\beta u+\gamma x=1\\\alpha s+\beta v+\gamma y=0\\ \alpha t+\beta w+\gamma z=0\\\delta r+\theta u+\lambda x=0\\\delta s+\theta v+\lambda y=1\\\delta t+\theta w+\lambda z=0\\\upsilon r+\phi u+\omega x=0\\\upsilon s+\phi v+\omega y=0\\\upsilon t+\phi w+\omega z=1\tag1\end{cases}$$

---

I didn't really try much due to the sheer ugliness of the system and how intimidating it looks. I want the $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\theta,\lambda,\upsilon,\phi,\omega$ to be in "matrix" form. Meaning if $\alpha$ is expressible as $ad-bc$, instead, write $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$. I have provided an example below:

---

> **Example:** Find $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\lambda$ from the following:$$\begin{cases}\alpha w+\beta y=1\\\alpha x+\beta z=0\\\gamma w+\lambda y=0\\\gamma x+\lambda z=1\tag2\end{cases}$$

---

I have found the solutions as $$\begin{align*} & \alpha=\frac z{wz-xy}=\frac z{\begin{bmatrix}w & x\\y & z\end{bmatrix}}\\ & \beta=\frac b{xy-wz}=\frac x{\begin{bmatrix}x & w\\z & y\end{bmatrix}}\\ & \gamma=\frac y{xy-wz}=\frac y{\begin{bmatrix}x & w\\z & y\end{bmatrix}}\\ & \lambda=\frac w{wz-xy}=\frac w{\begin{bmatrix}w & x\\y & z\end{bmatrix}}\end{align*}\tag3$$

---

From $(3)$, notice how instead of writing the denominator of each of the unknown as $wz-xy$ or $xy-wz$, I write it as a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}w & x\\y & z\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}x & w\\z & y\end{bmatrix}$ respectively.

**Note:** I *know* that this is probably one of the more "weirder" type of questions, but just try you're best..? I have no more attempts after this.

Comment: Can you inspire somewhat more by giving the context in which you came across this beast?

Comment: Check if you have $v$ the same as $\nu$. (Does $v$ appear twice in the 8th equation?)

Comment: @Qwerty Yeah sure! :) $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & \beta & \gamma\\\delta & \theta & \lambda\\\upsilon & \phi & \omega\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}r & s & t\\ u & v & w\\ x & y & z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Andrei Actually, the first one is upsilon (just happens to look like v... Should probably change that). And the other one is the normal $v$ from the English alphabet. There's also \omega, and $w$. (Note the second one is from the English alphabet)

Comment: @Frank I assume $r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z$ all are constants?

Comment: @Frank If you invert the $r, s, t, ..$ matrix, you have the solution. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixInverse.html

Comment: @Andrei Let's try not to..? I understand that, I'm just messing around with inverse matrices.

Comment: @Qwerty Yes. $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\theta,\lambda,\upsilon\phi,\omega$ are rational numbers.

Comment: @Frank Do you know how to invert a matrix? More specifically, do you know how to solve a system of linear equations of the form $A\cdot X=B$ , where $A$ is an invertible matrix?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes, I know how to invert a matrix. The only problem: our teacher only told us how to find the inverse through a calculator. So I'm just messing around, hopefully finding a formula to find the inverse of a matrix. (*by myself*)

Comment: @Frank Its good that you are trying to **learn** mathematics, but sometimes , it is better **not to re-invent the wheel**., especially if it is an unnecessarily tedious task.(And I think you might have to have some **extra** knowledge like Linear-Algebra to nail down the definition of an inverse-matrix from scratch)

Comment: @Qwerty I usually learn things by myself. Which is a terribly inefficient process. :/

Comment: @Frank But never loose the enthusiasm though.. Best of luck!

Comment: @Qwerty What if you re-invent the wheel and make an improvement to it? Just wondering... :P

Comment: @Frank Sure..A wonderful job.. Just you need to make sure that the wheel is circular and smooth. Don't make improvements on a rugged wheel.. :-P